# Is there another expression for $A^{-1}$, in terms of powers $A^n$ of $A$ for non-negative integers n ($A^0:=I_3$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}-2&1&2\\ \:1&-2&-3\\ \:1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$

(a) Determine $A^{−1}: \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\ \:-3&-2&-4\\ \:2&1&3\end{pmatrix}.$

(b) Show that $A^3+4A^2+A=I_3$
$\begin{pmatrix}-25&15&26\\ 27&-17&-29\\ 7&-4&-7\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}28&-16&-28\\ -28&20&32\\ -8&4&8\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&2\\ 1&-2&-3\\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$

(c) By considering the the equality in (b), find another expression for $A^{−1}$, in terms of powers $A^n$ of $A$ for non-negative integers $n$ ($A^0:= I_3$).

I'm assuming that by finding another expression of $A^{-1}$, that I can use powers of matrix. Is that right? I'm trying to learn how to solve (c).

I'm hoping for some tips to continue.

Comment: Cayley - Hamilton

Comment: Factor $(b)…..$

Comment: Basically, multiply $A^{-1}$ on both sides of the equality in (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $I_3=A^3+4A^2+A = A\cdot (A^2+4A+I_3) = (A^2+4A+I_3)\cdot A$. Therefore $A^{-1}=A^2+4A+I_3$.

Comment: Could I ask on how is "in terms of powers  of  for non-negative integers  (0:=3)" is applied? Sorry, if it's too basic.

Comment: $A^{-1}=A^2+4A^1+A^0$ (linear combination of powers of $A$).

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A **general** method for solving this kind of problem is to use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, which states that any matrix $A$ is a root in it's own characteristic polynomial. That is, if:
$$\det(A - \lambda I) = \lambda^n + c_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \dots + c_1 \lambda + c_0$$
Then:
$$A^n + c_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \dots + c_1A + c_0A^0 = 0$$

Now, the characteristic polynomial for your matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}-2&1&2\\ \:1&-2&-3\\ \:1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is the following.
$$\det(A - \lambda I) = \det\begin{bmatrix}-2 - \lambda & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -2-\lambda & -3 \\1 & 0 & -\lambda\end{bmatrix} = -\lambda^3 - 4\lambda^2 - \lambda + \lambda^0$$

Now replace $\lambda$ with $A$ and use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to get:
$$-A^3 - 4A^2 - A + A^0 = 0 \iff I_3 = A^0 = A^3 + 4A^2 + A = A(A^2 + 4A + I_3)$$
Implying that:
$$A^{-1} = A^2 + 4A + I_3$$

A general formula for the inverse of $A$ in terms of powers of $A$ is as follows:
$$A^{-1} = -\frac{1}{c_0}(A^{n-1} + c_{n-1}A^{n-2} + \dots + c_2A + c_1I)$$
Can you see why?

> Use Cayley-Hamilton: $$A^n + c_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \dots + c_1A + c_0A^0 = 0$$